# Discord.js guildCreate/guildDelete event can't get the owner tag of a new guild

Tags: node.js, discord.js

so the guildCreate and guildDelete events i have are supposed to send an embed to a channel with owner tag

```
client.on("guildDelete", async(guild) => {
    const EmbedLeave = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RED')
    .setTitle(`Left Guild: ${guild.name}.`)
    .setThumbnail(guild.iconURL())
    .setTimestamp()
    console.log(`Left Guild: ${guild.name}`);
    await client.channels.cache.get(`746423099871985755`).send(EmbedLeave)
    
    const EmbedLeave2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RED')
    .setTitle(`Left Guild: ${guild.name}.`)
    .setDescription(`**Guild owner:** ${guild.owner.user.tag}\n**Members size:** ${guild.memberCount}`)
    .setThumbnail(guild.iconURL())
    .setTimestamp()
    await client.channels.cache.get(`758356170926325790`).send(EmbedLeave2)
    

});

    client.on("guildCreate", async(guild) => {   
    const EmbedJoin = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#FFFF33')
    .setTitle(`Joined Guild: ${guild.name}!`)
    .setThumbnail(guild.iconURL())
    .setTimestamp()
    console.log(`Joined New Guild: ${guild.name}`);
    await client.channels.cache.get(`746423099871985755`).send(EmbedJoin)
     
    const EmbedJoin2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setTitle(`Joined Guild: ${guild.name}!`)
    .setDescription(`**Guild owner:** ${guild.owner.user.tag}\n**Members size:** ${guild.memberCount}`)
    .setThumbnail(guild.iconURL())
    .setTimestamp()
    await client.channels.cache.get(`758356170926325790`).send(EmbedJoin2)
});
    },
};
```

I'm using two embeds because I want to different embeds to different channels however at this part

```js
 .setDescription(`**Guild owner:** ${guild.owner.user.tag}\n**Members size:** ${guild.memberCount}`)
```

It usually works for servers the bot was in before (probably because of cache) but for completely new servers it gives error cannot read probably "tag" of undefined

I also tried to change the way i get the owner tag by doing this

```js
let owner = await client.users.cache.get(guild.ownerID)
.setDescription(`**Guild owner:** ${owner.tag}\n**Members size:** ${guild.memberCount}`)
```

but the same thing happens for new servers to give the same error
other functions like `guild.memberCount` `guild.iconURL()` work fine

Comment: I had my bot create a new guild on its own (thus triggering the event) and your code worked just fine. Maybe something with the permissions (although I think unlikely)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try either this (but this one uses the `message`):

```js
const { username } = await message.client.users.fetch(message.guild.ownerID);

// This is optional 
const serverOwner = username;
```

or this:

```js
const owner = await client.users.fetch(guild.ownerID);
```

I'm not sure if it works for you, I'm not at home rn so I cant't test it, but I had a similar problem:

I wasn't able to get the `guild owner` if he was offline. Probably because he was no longer cached. In this case the `first solution` worked for me

Comment: weird, I remember trying this but didn't work but thanks for telling me! it worked now

Comment: You should award them the bounty.

Comment: I tried but it says "You may award your bounty worth 50 rep in 16 hours"